# Docker Service connections in Azure DevOps Services

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I can see that you can create a Service Connection in Azure DevOps for:

1. Docker Registry
2. Docker Host

I can understand the Docker Registry - This allows you to configure a connection to some private registry which only allows authenticated users to log in and push/pull.
But I can't understand what is the Docker Host Service Connection. What is it good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Host Service Connection is a legacy of a unpublished task [Docker Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker).

The Docker Integration extension introduces two new service endpoints for Docker hosts and registries. The tasks default to using a local Docker host if available (this currently requires a custom VSTS agent), otherwise they require a Docker host connection to be provided.

Because this task is in an unpublished state at this time, we cannot use it. If necessary, it is recommended to use equivalent built-in docker and Docker Compose tasks.

**Docker Host service connection**:
Defines and secures a connection to a Docker host.

Ensure you protect your connection to the Docker host. [Learn more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).

Comment: Validating my understanding: This configures a host machine to use that will run the docker containers, so they won't necessarily run in one of the pool agents?

Comment: To run the pipeline, you need to specify the agent pool.

Comment: As Leo pointed out in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665570/how-to-use-docker-host-service-connection-in-azure-pipelines), Docker Host Service Connection is a legacy of a unpublished task [Docker Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker). So currently we cannot use it