# How to use Docker Host Service Connection in Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a `Docker Host` Service Connection in Azure Devops Services. But I can't see how I can refer to that service connection from the azure-pipeline.yml file.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use Docker Host Service Connection in Azure Pipelines

I am afraid that this should be a legacy of a **unpublished** task [Docker Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker).

[image]

[image]

**Because** this task is in an unpublished state at this time, we cannot use it. If necessary, it is recommended to use `docker` and `Docker Compose` tasks. That the reason why you could not find any task to use the Docker Host Service Connection.

If this option causes any confusion for you, you can go to our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ) to suggest removing it, which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

You could check [this blog](https://blog.jcorioland.io/archives/2016/08/19/build-push-and-run-docker-images-with-visual-studio-team-services.html) for some more details.

Comment: This is a confusing answer. The extension linked is deprecated, and recommends to use the built in VSTS tasks. I am using the built in tasks, and have an YAML action for DockerCompose@0 that has an advanced option where I can specify a service connection. If no service connection is specified then it defaults to the agent's host.